# TypeScript Advanced Types - A problem with Unreachable error inside generic function

Tags: typescript

I cannot found answer why `switch` in generic function does not cast my types inside branches.

My code is:

```
interface Id { id: number; }
enum Kind { square = "square", circle = "circle" }
interface Circle { kind: Kind.circle; radius: number; }
interface Square { kind: Kind.square; size: number; }
type Data = Circle | Square;
type ShapeModel<TData> = Id & TData;
class UnreachableError extends Error { public constructor(guard: never) { super(`Unsupported kind: ${JSON.stringify(guard)}`); } }

function myFunctionGeneric<TData extends Data>(data: TData): ShapeModel<TData> {
    switch (data.kind) {
        case Kind.circle:
            return { ...data, id: 1 };
        case Kind.square:
            return { ...data, id: 2 };
        default:
            throw new UnreachableError(data); // <-- UNEXPECTED
        // Argument of type 'TData' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
        // Type 'Data' is not assignable to type 'never'.
        // Type 'Circle' is not assignable to type 'never'.
        // ts(2345)
    }
}

const myCircleData: Circle = { kind: Kind.circle, radius: 42 };
const mySquareData: Square = { kind: Kind.square, size: 42 };

// I want this. I'm passing Circle and want receive ShapeModel<Circle>
const myCircleModel: ShapeModel<Circle> = myFunctionGeneric(myCircleData);

// I want this. I'm passing Square and want receive ShapeModel<Square>
const mySquareModel: ShapeModel<Square> = myFunctionGeneric(mySquareData);
```

This approach work correctly without generic `TData`.

Can anybody explain, why TypeScript is not able to decide what the type in the branch?

Comment: Seems to be related to this open issue on the Typescript issue tracker: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/36772

Answer (score 3):

For a type to be narrowed it needs to be a union, there is no union here, it is the generic type parameter `TData`. Sure, that extends a union. But TS will not try to narrow this. If you think about it, it would be pretty difficult to narrow, `TData` can be a subtype of `Circle` so you can't narrow to `Circle` in the switch cases, it would be some conditional type.

The simplest solution would be to have a public signature with the generics, and a private signature with simpler unions that can be narrowed by typescript.

```
function myFunctionGeneric<TData extends Data>(data: TData): ShapeModel<TData>
function myFunctionGeneric(data: Data): ShapeModel<Data> {
    switch (data.kind) {
        case Kind.circle:
            return { ...data, id: 1 };
        case Kind.square:
            return { ...data, id: 2 };
        default:
            throw new UnreachableError(data); 
    }
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=19&ssc=2&pln=8&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIBNkG9nHQLmRAFcBbAI2gG5kBfAWACgITTkBpUTHAZwEdicKCgC8yAET9Bw8QBpkCYFAQAbURMXK14uk1CRYiFAGElqlDgDWXQpxDoAdJvM0ocdMGI9CrSlBoMjPrQ8EjIAMoCQhbI1va2XA5S0TQ8wABeED5kfgFMYACeAA4oACJwYHDIYqZaKAA+EVHCVPnFKOEAFnAlALIA9ugQKgA8ACrllQB81WiYAGTIExVwrYyqcDw8yACqIMKI3eRqAKJQUP1QyBAAHpD222cXVzhFxMfACAr9IDxgUMQEGBLgAKADm0gIRAgADdoABKbDIHjEEpQEEAAz2KKKRUukEwcShABIsAApcIAeQAckl-qAwcAYAVwZD4bQMfCArpGEwYMQQEDgD9kKQCgAxAVCn4AcRY0E+40mVVu93Q22VUxB6BWhGWlXhhC6PQgAyGo31cCmfKlYGFIFFEtt9rlIAVCG1uuQysNEW6fUGwxGmuwTGQ4eRAHdgGAEJ1kJ7Kg4iYisGGIxmEJsUHZHM41Ph0xni8hhGBiFAHTgHDWdZV5HhCABGOhrEvhrM8HOJZLCQuMdvFssVqvIGsOOtwBtQgBMraLxaG8GIKjA-cHGbAnQukehu72BzjcGOECeoMnXOQC8CgSYCB+f0dtXMysIz7UsysNg4iXzEHkbgeF4hAACxzrQaz3r8YCOpE0gQK+TTwZ+sTfrmSTNP+yIZFkyBgfOvKMAA9ERaDIJGcDgMgW7ADwDhoAA5GwRSbGkIBgsg74oJRmAUVRwhIMAcJ+iaZpBlx1rrA+MFilxYkqEa-qmoGowSbMYqSoKdqyvKUCfCCslmGoPprEwJFkXxME0XRjHMaxDJIdEyA8eRlEwQJEBCR0SnySMcHRJJUGPmK-nCPJimiSpfmYTMYgac6OlunpHohZhJlAA)

Comment: *For a type to be narrowed it needs to be a union* - not true; if you write a user-defined type guard `function isCircle(obj: Data): obj is Circle { return obj.kind === Kind.circle; }` then you can use `if(isCircle(data)) { ... }` to narrow data's type to `TData & Circle`.

Comment: @kaya3 I think *narrowed* may also imply that the `else` case would also have a more specific type where as a custom assertion wouldn't.  A type can't "narrow" to an intersection including the original type, but an intersection of generic and union (`TData & Data`) will narrow to intersection of generic and specific instances of the union (`TData & Circle`) [as I demonstrate in my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60352928/5827215)

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen The [Typescript docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#using-type-predicates) say that when a user-defined type guard *"is called with some variable, TypeScript will **narrow** that variable to that specific type if the original type is compatible"* (emphasis in original), so the word "narrow" is still correct there. That said, your answer is wonderfully simple!

Answer (score 2):

Typescript can only do a discriminated union if the variable is known to be a union correct? then you can force it to be by making the argument type `TData & Data`, this means that typescript statically knows your variable can be narrowed to `TData & Circle` or `TData & Square` exactly as you'd expect and the generic behaviour is preserved.  ([Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=20&ssc=20&pln=16&pc=46#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIBNkG9nHQLmRAFcBbAI2gG5kBfAWACgITTkBpUTHAZwEdicKCgC8yAET9Bw8QBpkCYFAQAbURMXK14uk1CRYiFAGElqlDgDWXQpxDoAdJvM0ocdMGI9CrSlBoMjPrQ8EjIAMoCQhbI1va2XA5S0TQ8wABeED5kfgFMYACeAA4oACJwYHDIYqZaKAA%20EVHCVPnFKOEAFnAlALIA9ugQKgA8ACrllQB81WiYAGTIExVwrYyqcDw8yACqIMKI3eRqAKJQUP1QyBAAHpD222cXVzhFxMfACAr9IDxgUMQEGBLgAKADm0gIRAgADdoABKbDIHjEEpQEEAAz2KKKRUukEwcShABIsAApcIAeQAckl-qAwcAYAVwZD4bQMfCArpGEwYMQQEDgD9kKQCgAxAVCn4AcRY0E%2040mVVu93Q22VUxB6BWhGVyEWy0q8MIXR6EAGQ1GRrgMywTGQjuRAHdgGAEJ1kNqVg4iYj7YwnUGFJsUHZHM41PgHcHY8IwMQoCAkQ5UzrKvI8IQAIx0Naxx0IUMcRLJYTRwMFoPxxPJnCphzpuCZqEAJjzMdjQ3gxBUYArVaDYE6F2d0LHewOHrgxwgT1BTa5nZ5gSYCB%20f1FBVq5mVhB3almVhsJfsTjMankbg8XkIABZ27Q1uvfmAt5FpBA901P0fYifwySZoIHkNJMnvR81iYAB6aDkGdS5LG2ddzggIEVAKNcNzfMUDwtQZhlNbo%20gI0Y8JmMQxUlQUwGFEA5RABUEBBXCLy-FYl3WbD32Ay1CIiYj8KtEYP2iCit2o6V6PlKBPhYgpROEZUuSAA))

```
function myFunctionGeneric<TData extends Data>(data: Data & TData): ShapeModel<TData>
                                                  //  ^ this fixes it.
```

Answer (score 0):

To make things clearer, pay special attention to the new signature for UnreachableError. Note also that I added an unsupported type to the union type for demonstration purposes. Now it compiles, and still throws an error if a value of the same type as the illegal one added to the Union type is passed to your function:

```
interface Id { id: number; }
enum Kind { square = "square", circle = "circle" , anyData = 'anyData'}
interface Circle { kind: Kind.circle; radius: number; }
interface Square { kind: Kind.square; size: number; }
interface AnyData { kind: Kind.anyData; prop: string; }

type Data = Circle | Square | AnyData;
type ShapeModel<TData> = Id & TData;
class UnreachableError extends Error { public constructor(guard: any) { super(`Unsupported kind: ${JSON.stringify(guard)}`); } }

function myFunctionGeneric<TData extends Data>(data: TData): ShapeModel<TData> {
    switch (data.kind) {
        case Kind.circle:
            return { ...data, id: 1 };
        case Kind.square:
            return { ...data, id: 2 };
        default:
            throw new UnreachableError(data); 
    }
}
const myCircleData: Circle = { kind: Kind.circle, radius: 42 };
const mySquareData: Square = { kind: Kind.square, size: 42 };
const myAnyData : AnyData = {kind: Kind.anyData , prop: 'aProp'}
// I want this. I'm passing Circle and want receive ShapeModel<Circle>
const myCircleModel: ShapeModel<Circle> = myFunctionGeneric(myCircleData);

// I want this. I'm passing Square and want receive ShapeModel<Square>
const mySquareModel: ShapeModel<Square> = myFunctionGeneric(mySquareData);
```

Now, if you try this:

```
const myAnyDataModel: ShapeModel<AnyData> = myFunctionGeneric(myAnyData)
```

You will get the expected error:

```
Error: Unsupported kind: {"kind":"anyData","prop":"aProp"}
    at myFunctionGeneric
```

Comment: Yes, this was my intention. If any developer add a new type `AnyData` into the union `Data`, the compiler will show all places where the union is used. So you will be able to see usage of the new type `AnyData` around all your code base. In another words, if you add `AnyData` you need to handle it inside `myFunctionGeneric `.

Comment: [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=17&ssc=1&pln=19&pc=1#) try to uncomment lines 17-18. It shown my intention in my question

Answer (score -2):

In typescript `never` is a type that no actual value can ever take. Your code editor, for example vscode, will tell you right away. Change `never` to `any` in the definition for UnreachableError:

```
class UnreachableError extends Error { public constructor(guard: any) { super(`Unsupported kind: ${JSON.stringify(guard)}`); } }
```

Comment: `UnreachableError` is used here in order to ensure the switch is exhaustive. If someone adds another option to the union the user want to get an error in the function.

Comment: @titian-cernicova-dragomir , the negative mark is unwarranted as the error will actually be thrown. Have you actually tried the code change I mentioned?

Comment: Moreover, @titian-cernicova-dragomir, UnreachableError's signature was the issue there. Not the approach itself. Your approach is quite logic. It's only  the type of the parameter passed to UnreachableError that you have to change.If you want to maintain `never` as the type, then you will have to cast the value as in `throw new UnreachableError(data as never);` .

Comment: The down vote is not mine. But I stand by the comment. The point is that on the default branch the type of data SHOULD be never. If it is not never, (because someone added a new optiion to the union) there should be an error. Your aproach does not do this

Comment: Look https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#exhaustiveness-checking

Comment: Did it matter to you that your code did not compile?

Comment: Max A Did you really read my answer? Expletives won't change the fact that your code as you posted it would NEVER compile. And I stand by what I said too, for the matter. You set a parameter's type to `never` and try to call the method. Could you call it without casting the given argument to `never` first? NO.

Comment: There is no problem at all with a constructor or function taking `never` as its parameter type; it can be called in branches where some variable is narrowed to type `never`. See e.g. [Playground Link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAKhDOwoF4oHIBmB7LaoB90AjAQwCc0BuAWACg6MBXAOwGNgBLLZqFsiEqwAWJIgBsIACgAeALijMIANwhkAlPMUqyUAN50ohqMCFksAdwURLAUTJmyktTVoBfOgxbsuPYAmAy8nCIGlBKWBwAJnoGRhwYUDIoyKiYOGhqMbRGOVCs3PBYEgB0YlgA5pJoAGI4AIQZLjmuUBBi8NDxidLJqaQUmfrZuYb5zIUlZZVoAELkDc6xhi1tHVkjhnwCwqISMovDy3TutEA) The OP's problem is that the `switch` statement is not doing this narrowing.

Comment: @kaya3 Does it make sense to you semantically though? What meaning are you conveying to somebody that will read your code later in the future?

Comment: Yes, it makes perfect sense. The meaning is "this function will be used to check at compile-time that the branches I think are unreachable are actually unreachable when called with correctly-typed arguments, and it will be used to check at runtime that the function is not called with incorrectly-typed arguments". Typescript's type checker is not 100% safe [and is not intended to be](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/TypeScript-Design-Goals): *"Non-goals: ... Apply a sound or "provably correct" type system."* so it's sometimes sensible to check again at runtime.

Comment: Seems contrived to me. I will agree to disagree with you on that one pal. As long as we both know what we're coding and that his code compiles, and so does mine, I will be perfectly happy to leave it at that. Cheers

Comment: You are, of course, free to have the opinion that the rationale for having such a function is "contrived". But your answer doesn't address the question of how to make Typescript narrow `data`'s type to `never` in the unreachable branch. The fact that your code compiles without errors is beside the point, because it doesn't do what the OP wants.

Comment: I was not trying to narrow down the type to `never` actually and on that aspect you are right; even though "exhaustiveness checking" does reduce a variable to only `never`, and it's mention in the docs, I am not comfortable with the semantics of `never` being used as function arguments anyway. `never` being a bottom type, the truth is I will almost never use it directly. Now others in the typescript community do, I won't.